Proof that any non-trivially recurrent trajectory is a dense subset of exactly one quasiminimal
A trajectory of a flow on a (compact, orientable) surface with finitely many singularities is said to be recurrent if any point on the trajectory is contained in the limit set of the trajectory. A trajectory is called non-trivially recurrent if it is recurrent but not closed. The closure of a non-trivially recurrent trajectory is called a quasiminimal.
It seems to be a classical result proven by Maier that any non-trivially recurrent trajectory is a dense subset of exactly one quasiminimal. However, I struggle to come up with a proof of this fact and I cannot find the original proof, so I'd be happy to hear your ideas.
